# Accessing array properties using foreign keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

How can we access value from a multidimensional array using key/value pair when key is from another array ? Both tricks I know return nothing!!. thanks

```
    var keySource = {doo: "loo"}
    var target = [{foo: "a", doo: "b"}, {foo: "c", doo: "d"}]

    var key = Object.keys(keySource );     


    /*-------this doesn't work---*/

    target[0]['key']; // no result
    target[0].key;    // no result


    /*-------this works fine---*/
    something[0]['doo'];  // b
    something[0].doo;     // b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` itself is actually an array so you will need to use an index

```js
var keySource = {
  doo: "loo"
}
var target = [{
  foo: "a",
  doo: "b"
}, {
  foo: "c",
  doo: "d"
}]

var key = Object.keys(keySource);
console.log(target[0][key[0]]);
```

Comment: @AsadButt, no problem, hope it helped :)